# How the range of matrix column space is related to number of columns it has?

Tags: matrices

More specifically, why a matrix having a column space range of $\mathbb{R}^m$ should have at least $m$ number of columns in it  i.e: number of columns $\geq m$?

Comment: Instead of *range*, you perhaps mean the *dimension* of the column space of a matrix.  Or perhaps you mean the *range* of the linear transformation represented by multiplication of a matrix.  Your Question body could be more clearly phrased if you find it necessary to also introduce $\mathbb{R}^m$ as an additional concept.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking about if given a linear transformation: $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $v \mapsto Av$, where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $v$ is an $n$ dimensional vector. Why is it that $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T)) \leq m$. It basically comes down to the [Rank Nullity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), which states: 
$$\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T)) + \dim(\operatorname{Ker}(T)) = \dim(\mathbb{R}^m) = m$$
Since this equality holds and dimension of a space will be non-negative, we have that:
$$\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T)) \leq m.$$